# Again ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 11: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

I am getting error

> ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 11: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Both column are identical, i.e.

- For table hvcrateslot has column `suplayer` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
- For table layer       has column `suplayer` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,

The latest foreign key error states

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2017-04-11 21:57:46 0x700003ab1000 Error in foreign key constraint of table clasdbclone/layer:
 FOREIGN KEY (`suplayer`) REFERENCES hvcrateslot(`suplayer`) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
PRIMARY KEY (`layer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
```

To my naive surprise if I limit the amount of primary keys in the hvcrateslot table, everything works.

Here is my minimum working DDL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hvcrateslot`;
CREATE TABLE `hvcrateslot` (
`hvcrate` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`hvslot` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`hvsubslot` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`suplayer` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`hvcrate`,`hvslot`,`hvsubslot`,`suplayer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `layer`;
CREATE TABLE `layer` (
`layer` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`suplayer` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX (`suplayer`),
CONSTRAINT `superlayer` FOREIGN KEY (`suplayer`) 
REFERENCES hvcrateslot(`suplayer`) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT
PRIMARY KEY (`layer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: The referenced column must have an index on it (or be first in the list of a multi-column index).  Add an index on `hvcrateslot.suplayer` and the FK creation should succeed.

Comment: Adding an index to hvcrateslot.suplayer worked. Side question, I know FK should be on unique values, like PK. I removed hvcrateslot.suplayer as a PK, but I did index it. The FK was created successfully, but I have not found any documentation on if this technique is proper, and or pitfalls of having an indexed value a FK without it being a PK. Is it too much for this thread to ask for more information on indexing a column without the column being a PK?